# Rotation Grapples customization in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

In fabricjs when we place an object on the canvas and select it, the grapples appear. For rotation there is this grapple which appears at the end.

Is there a way in fabric to hide the rotation grapple and instead have the drag grapples do the rotation as well, like the corner grapples could be used for rotation?

Any customization on this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This behavior was removed in v1.0 but we have a ticket marked "possible feature" to bring this functionality alongside existing one — https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/623

Answer (score 0):

You can easily customise the handles, see the documentation here http://fabricjs.com/customization/